How to convert simpleproxy trace binary output to text
I have simpleproxy running on an Ubuntu server, but there are some issues with one of my proxies, so I restarted the proxy with the -rt flag to trace it & output to a file.  The only issue is that the file is in binary format so I'm getting garbled output with some actual text in it that seems to be separating the output.  I haven't been able to find any documentation about this. How do I convert it to text?
Example:
��Ͽ�uPm���}���`�̖�Q�������u����(����(+�Y�ݱ̂܈#eFC
                                              �jG�}��T\�?���.=0ɼ��S�;l�i�*��fg�c�F�
>�<��\��@� ���6����>��Υ=�Kt��
��8*�s��mj�e= ����ϑ��5����t5��Y�I�#�W�īP�S��kh������э�)


sent this with some typos.  the flag is -t & the text above that block of binary is this:
------------- Read from: 69.84.183.38:443 ---------------
